# Change making problem with Euro system and Greedy algorithm

Tags: proof-verification, algorithms, induction, proof-explanation

Prove that the Euro system $c = (200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1)$ is canonical.

To do this I am using *Definition 2* and *Theorem 2* from https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.0400.pdf which state:

> Definition 2: A coin system \$ is non-canonical if there is an $x$ with
> $\vert GRD_\$(x) \vert $ $>$ $\vert OPT_\$(x) \vert$, and such $x$ is called a counterexample of \$.
>
> Theorem 2: Let $\$_1 = \langle c_m, c_{m-1}, · · · , c_2, 1 \rangle$ and $\$_2 = \langle c_{m+1}, c_m, · · · , c_2, 1\rangle $ be two coin systems such that $\$_1$ is canonical but $\$_2$ is not. Then there is some $k$ such that $k·c_m < c_{m+1} < (k+1)·c_m$ and $(k+1)·c_m$ is a counterexample of $\$_2$.

I attempt this proof by choosing $\$_1 = (100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1)$ and $\$_2=c$.

Assuming by contradiction that $c$ is non-canonical then *Theorem 2* leads us to finding $k=3$ and therefore our counterexample would be $x=400$.

In this case, $GRD_\$(400)=(2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ and $OPT_\$(400)=(2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ which is a contradiction to *Definition 2* so $c$ is canonical.

**Question**

My question is, how can I easily show that my chosen $\$_1$ is canonical. Furthermore, is there a way to prove *Theorem 2*?

Comment: Might it not be easier to start from a definition of *canonical* and prove that the definition applies to the euro money?

Comment: @GerryMyerson A coin system is canonical if an only if the greedy algorithm produces an optimal solution for any $x$. In my opinion, it would be harder to prove it directly. Do you have any insight on how to prove Theorem 2?